# Getting value from cells horizontally

Tags: phpexcel

[image]

Hi, I have an excel sheet like the one posted above. I am trying to retrieve data from this spreadsheet and insert it into a database. An example of a few entries would be,

[personnel_no: 35, name: John, Day: 01, Value: N],

[personnel_no: 35, name: John, Day: 02, Value: N],

[personnel_no: 35, name: John, Day: 03, Value: O]

I know how to create a loop that will go through the spreadsheet by rowss but i'm stumped as to how to do it by column. I've read that phpexcel has a column iterator function but im not even sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure why you even need the column iterator for this, because all your data is tabulated by row....

```
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $rowData = $worksheet->toArray('A'.$row->getRowIndex().':AG'.$row->getRowIndex());

    ... var_dump($rowData);
    ... insert data from $rowData into the database
}
```

If you want to read more about iterators, take a look at `28iterator.php` in `/Examples`